# Error's on Configuration File Parsing

Tags: c++, fileparsing

I am having some problems with some sample coding I have. Ideally I want a file that will have key words, that have data (int and strings) associated with them that can be changed. I will have duration (int), destination(string), and source(source) that can be edited at any time. This will be ultimately for ease of use backing up files for a set time in days, where they are and where they are going.

This is the sample code I have, I have fixed quit a few errors but am stuck on the last couple. Or is there an easier way about doing this? Sorry its all jumbled, I am pretty new C++...

Thank you for the help, I know its a lot to go through. Maybe someone has a good tutorial on easy configuration file parsing I could read up on also?

My gcc version is 4.4.7

The errors I am recieving are:

g++ configFile.cpp
configFile.cpp:36: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class Convert’
configFile.cpp: In static member function ‘static T Convert::string_to_T(const std::string&)’:
configFile.cpp:31: error: there are no arguments to ‘exitWithError’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘exitWithError’ must be available
configFile.cpp:31: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Convert
{

public:
template <typename T>
static std::string T_to_string(T const &val) 
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << val;

    return ostr.str();
}

template <typename T>
static T string_to_T(std::string const &val) 
{
    std::istringstream istr(val);
    T returnVal;

    if (!(istr >> returnVal))
        exitWithError("CFG: Not a valid " + (std::string)typeid(T).name() + " received!\n");

    return returnVal;
}

template <>
static std::string string_to_T(std::string const &val)
{

    return val;
}
};

void exitWithError(const std::string &error) 
{
std::cout << error;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cin.get();

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

class ConfigFile
{

private:
std::map<std::string, std::string> contents;
std::string fName;

void removeComment(std::string &line) const
{
    if (line.find(';') != line.npos)
        line.erase(line.find(';'));
}

bool onlyWhitespace(const std::string &line) const
{
    return (line.find_first_not_of(' ') == line.npos);
}

bool validLine(const std::string &line) const
{
    std::string temp = line;
    temp.erase(0, temp.find_first_not_of("\t "));

    if (temp[0] == '=')

        return false;

    for (size_t i = temp.find('=') + 1; i < temp.length(); i++)

                    if (temp[i] != ' ')

            return true;

    return false;
}

void extractKey(std::string &key, size_t const &sepPos, const std::string &line) const
{
    key = line.substr(0, sepPos);
    if (key.find('\t') != line.npos || key.find(' ') != line.npos)
        key.erase(key.find_first_of("\t "));
}
void extractValue(std::string &value, size_t const &sepPos, const std::string &line) const
{
    value = line.substr(sepPos + 1);
    value.erase(0, value.find_first_not_of("\t "));
    value.erase(value.find_last_not_of("\t ") + 1);
}
void extractContents(const std::string &line) 
{
    std::string temp = line;
    temp.erase(0, temp.find_first_not_of("\t "));
    size_t sepPos = temp.find('=');
    std::string key, value;
    extractKey(key, sepPos, temp);
    extractValue(value, sepPos, temp);

    if (!keyExists(key))
        contents.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));
    else
        exitWithError("CFG: Can only have unique key names!\n");
}
void parseLine(const std::string &line, size_t const lineNo)
{
    if (line.find('=') == line.npos)
        exitWithError("CFG: Couldn't find separator on line: " + Convert::T_to_string(lineNo) + "\n");

    if (!validLine(line))
        exitWithError("CFG: Bad format for line: " + Convert::T_to_string(lineNo) + "\n");

    extractContents(line);
}
void ExtractKeys()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(fName.c_str());
    if (!file)
        exitWithError("CFG: File " + fName + " couldn't be found!\n");

    std::string line;
    size_t lineNo = 0;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {

        lineNo++;
        std::string temp = line;
        if (temp.empty())
            continue;

        removeComment(temp);
        if (onlyWhitespace(temp))
            continue;

        parseLine(temp, lineNo);
    }
    file.close();
}
public:
ConfigFile(const std::string &fName)
{
    this->fName = fName;
    ExtractKeys();
}
bool keyExists(const std::string &key) const
{
    return contents.find(key) != contents.end();
}
template <typename ValueType>

ValueType getValueOfKey(const std::string &key, ValueType const &defaultValue = ValueType()) const
{
    if (!keyExists(key))
        return defaultValue;

    return Convert::string_to_T<ValueType>(contents.find(key)->second);
}
};

int main()
{

ConfigFile cfg("config.cfg");



bool exists = cfg.keyExists("car");

std::cout << "car key: " << std::boolalpha << exists << "\n";

exists = cfg.keyExists("fruits");

std::cout << "fruits key: " << exists << "\n";



std::string someValue = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("mykey", "Unknown");

std::cout << "value of key mykey: " << someValue << "\n";

std::string carValue = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("car");

std::cout << "value of key car: " << carValue << "\n";

double doubleVal = cfg.getValueOfKey<double>("double");

std::cout << "value of key double: " << doubleVal << "\n\n";



std::cin.get();

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code, were you trying to specialize it?

```
template <>
static std::string string_to_T(std::string const &val)
{

    return val;
}
```

If that is the case, explicit specialization need to be defined outside of the class as the error says (`explicit specialization in non-namespace scope`):

```
template <>
std::string Convert::string_to_T<std::string>(std::string const &val)
{

    return val;
}
```

Also, you need `exitWithError` before you use it in `Convert` or forward declare it since the compiler has not seen it yet when you use it in `Convert`. Move it before the definition of `Convert`:

```
void exitWithError(const std::string &error) 
{
std::cout << error;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cin.get();

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// Or just forward declare void exitWithError(const std::string &);

class Convert
{ ....
```

Comment: Thank you for catching my placement error with "exitWithError". For the specialized error, I don't have to have it specialized. Fom my research it seemed like a good way to accomplish what i am going for. Do you recommend any other options? I am still getting any error for explicit specialization, but will report when I can figure out my mistake. Thank you Jesse.

Comment: @user2630969: Specialization looked like the way to go. [Here is an example of your code that compiled for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6a4810be9bc5b661781797df409dfc02-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Comment: Thank you Jesse, this is exactly what I am was trying to do. Sending some good vibes your way!